# Jupyter display several images

Tags: python, image, ipython, jupyter

I've got a list of image urls, and want to display them in Jupyter.
As it is ok for one single image, no image is displayed when looping over the list:

Here's the list:

```py
liste_images = ['http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=447344&type=card',
 'http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=450248&type=card',
 'http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=447345&type=card',
 'http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=450252&type=card',
 'http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=469854&type=card',
 'http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=466953&type=card',
 'http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=469851&type=card',
 'http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=461108&type=card',
 'http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=461109&type=card',
 'http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=461107&type=card']
```

and the way I tried:

```py
import requests
from IPython.display import Image
for url_image_carte in liste_images:
    Image(requests.get(url_image_carte).content)
```

Finally, the image from Jupyter session (individual image rendering is OK):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `IPython.display.display` like so:

```
import requests
from IPython.display import Image, display
for url_image_carte in liste_images:
    display( Image(requests.get(url_image_carte).content) ) #added display
```